# How to write lambda expression for two or more anonymous functions in java?

Tags: java, java-8

Suppose I have **interface A** which has only  one method declared like below:

```
interface A{        
    void print();           
}
```

now with old java style we'll use this in anonymous way like below:

```
new A() {           
        @Override
        public void print() {
            System.out.println("in a print method");                
        }           
};
```

and with lambda expression we'll use it like below:

```
() -> "A1";
```

now my question is if interface A has two methods declared like below:

```
interface A{        
   void print();    
   void display();          
}
```

and its old way of anonymous function utilization is like below:

```
  new A() {         
        @Override
        public void print() {
            System.out.println("in print");

        }

        @Override
        public void display() {
            System.out.println("in display");

        }       

    };
```

Now how to convert display method to lambda? or we are not allowed to do this; if not why not? Why cant we represent it like

> print() -> "printing"

and

> display() -> "displaying"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't. A lambda expression can only be used for a "functional" interface - one that has only one non-default method.

For the "why" you'd have to ask the language designers, but my take on it is that lambda expressions are a shorthand for *single* blocks of code, whereas a group of related blocks treated as a unit would be better represented as a proper class.  For cases like your example in the question, the real answer would be to modify the API so that instead of using a single `A` interface with two methods it uses two separate functional interfaces for the two functions `APrinter` and `ADisplayer`, which could then be implemented by separate lambdas.

Answer (score 2):

You can't but you can "transform" A into a functional interface by providing a default implementation for one of the two methods, for example:

```
public interface B extends A {
    default void print() {}
}

B lambda = () -> displaySomething();
```

Alternatively you can provide [a static factory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23373921/829571).