# Java idiom for lambdas with non-SAM interfaces

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

In Java, interfaces with a single abstract method (i.e., SAM types or functional interfaces) can be elegantly implemented with lambda instead of an anonymous class:

```
    // SAM ActionListener with anonymous implementation
    button.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(Event e){
                System.out.println("button via anon!");
            }
        }
    );
```

can be replaced with:

```
    // SAM ActionListener with lambda implementation
    button.addActionListener(
        e -> System.out.println("button via lambda!")
    );
```

But for interfaces with multiple abstract methods, lambda cannot be directly applied. For example, `java.awt.event.WindowListener` has seven methods. But often a chunk a code is only interested in defining one of these seven methods.

To implement the behavior with an anonymous class override, we can:

```
    // non-SAM with adapter implementation with override
    window.addWindowListener(
        new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowOpened(Event e){
                System.out.println("WindowAdapter opened via override!");
            }
        }
    );
```

but is there a more elegant way with lambdas?

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ActionListener {
    void actionPerformed(Event e);
}

public interface WindowListener {
    void windowOpened(Event e);

    void windowClosing(Event e);
}

public class WindowAdapter implements WindowListener {

    public void windowOpened(Event e){
        System.out.println("windowOpened in adapter!");
    }

    public void windowClosing(Event e){
        System.out.println("windowClosing in adapter!");
    }
}
```

---

**Note**: @maythesource.com asked a similar, but broader question: "*What would someone do with a MouseListener if they wanted to implement multiple methods within the anonymous class?*" The most upvoted and accepted answer is to use an anonymous implementation. My question is about an elegant lambda solution for non-SAM types. Therefore, **this question is not a duplicate** of [Java 8 Lambda Expressions - what about multiple methods in nested class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21833537/3342253).

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most elegant way I have found is to use an anonymous bridge:

```
    // SAM bridge with lambda implementation
    window.addWindowListener(
        WindowBridge.windowOpened(
            b -> System.out.println("opening via lambda!")
        )
    );
```

which, like the SAM type scenario, is cleaner than the anonymous adapter:

```
    // non-SAM with adapter implementation with override
    window.addWindowListener(
        new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowOpened(Event e){
                System.out.println("WindowAdapter opened via override!");
            }
        }
    );
```

but it does require a slightly awkward bridge with a static factory:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public interface WindowBridge {

    // SAM for this method
    public abstract class WindowOpened extends WindowAdapter {
        public abstract void windowOpened(Event e);
    }

    // factory bridge
    public static WindowOpened windowOpened(Consumer<Event> c) {
        return new WindowOpened() {
            public void windowOpened(Event e){
                c.accept(e);
            }
        };
    }

    // SAM for this method
    public abstract class WindowClosing extends WindowAdapter {
        public abstract void windowClosing(Event e);
    }

    // factory bridge
    public static WindowClosing windowClosing(Consumer<Event> c) {
        return new WindowClosing() {
            public void windowClosing(Event e){
                c.accept(e);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Only slightly cleaner.

Comment: I just noticed that @Brian Goetz answered this question in http://stackoverflow.com/a/23373921/3342253 with his "officially recommended pattern".

Comment: Yeah, agreed @immibis - the additional static bridge method, while hidden, is still a little tricky. The application code is cleaner like in the SAM scenario, though.

Comment: actually I find this method very nice and readable.  The bridge is indeed a bit awkward, but on the calling side it is immediately visible what's happening.

Comment: What’s strange about this solution is the creation of these obsolete types `WindowOpened` and `WindowClosing` whereas the solution would also work without them, i.e. creating anonymous subclasses of `WindowAdapter` directly. It’s also unclear why `WindowBridge` is an `interface` as it is not meant to be implemented by anyone.

Comment: Not sure for what you need the 'WindowBridge'. I find the solution of @Holger from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21851111/1465758) easier ...

Answer (score 11):

In [Brian Goetz' answer to the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23373921/3342253), he suggested using static factory methods. In this case it's a bit tedious, since `WindowListener` defines *seven* handler methods, so you'd need to define seven static factory methods. This isn't that bad, though, since there is already a `WindowAdapter` class that provides empty implementations of all of the methods. (If there isn't one, you'd have to define your own equivalent.) Here's how I'd do it:

```
class WLFactory {
    public static WindowListener windowOpened(Consumer<WindowEvent> c) {
        return new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) { c.accept(e); }
        };
    }

    public static WindowListener windowClosing(Consumer<WindowEvent> c) {
        return new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) { c.accept(e); }
        };
    }

    // ...
}
```

[(The other 253 cases are analogous.)](http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/humor_proof.html)

Each factory method creates a subclass of `WindowAdapter` that overrides the appropriate method to call the lambda expression that's passed in. No need for additional adapter or bridge classes.

It would be used as follows:

```
window.addWindowListener(WLFactory.windowOpened(we -> System.out.println("opened")));
```

Comment: Thanks, +Stuart Marks! It looks like we agree on cleanest lambda solution, as well as the override solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to propose a rather generic solution for this: One can use [Dynamic Proxy Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html) to generate the implementation of the interface. Such a proxy could simply ignore all methods, except for the method for which an appropriate `Consumer` was specified as a lambda.

Of course, reflection always has to be used with care. But the advantage is that it works "out of the box" with **any** MAM-interface-type (Multiple Abstract Method).

There's no need to create dozens or hundreds of bridge methods for all the interfaces and their methods. Just create a proxy that is an "empty" implementation of the interface, and pass in a single method implementation as a lambda.

A basic example implementation is here, showing that it may be used concisely  and generically for different interfaces, like `WindowListener`, `MouseListener` and `ComponentListener`:

```
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;

class LambdaDelegatorTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        WindowListener w =
            LambdaDelegators.create(WindowListener.class, "windowClosed",
                e -> System.out.println("Window closed"));

        w.windowActivated(null);
        w.windowClosed(null);

        MouseListener m =
            LambdaDelegators.create(MouseListener.class, "mouseExited",
                e -> System.out.println("Mouse exited"));

        m.mouseClicked(null);
        m.mouseExited(null);

        ComponentListener c =
            LambdaDelegators.create(ComponentListener.class, "componentShown",
                e -> System.out.println("Component shown"));

        c.componentHidden(null);
        c.componentShown(null);

    }
}

class LambdaDelegators
{
    public static <T> T create(Class<T> c, String methodName,
        Consumer<Object[]> consumer)
    {
        Function<Object[], Object> function = new Function<Object[], Object>()
        {
            @Override
            public Object apply(Object[] t)
            {
                consumer.accept(t);
                return null;
            }
        };
        return createFromFunction(c, methodName, function);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static <T> T createFromFunction(Class<T> c, String methodName,
        Function<Object[], Object> function)
    {
        Class<?> classes[] = new Class[1];
        classes[0] = c;
        Object proxy =
            Proxy.newProxyInstance(c.getClassLoader(), classes,
                new LambdaDelegator(methodName, function));
        return (T) proxy;
    }

    private LambdaDelegators()
    {

    }
}

class LambdaDelegator implements InvocationHandler
{
    private static final Method hashCodeMethod;
    private static final Method equalsMethod;
    private static final Method toStringMethod;
    static
    {
        try
        {
            hashCodeMethod = Object.class.getMethod(
                "hashCode", (Class<?>[]) null);
            equalsMethod = Object.class.getMethod(
                "equals", new Class[] { Object.class });
            toStringMethod = Object.class.getMethod(
                "toString", (Class<?>[]) null);
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
        {
            throw new NoSuchMethodError(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private final String methodName;
    private final Function<Object[], Object> function;

    public LambdaDelegator(String methodName,
        Function<Object[], Object> function)
    {
        this.methodName = methodName;
        this.function = function;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args)
        throws Throwable
    {
        Class<?> declaringClass = m.getDeclaringClass();
        if (declaringClass == Object.class)
        {
            if (m.equals(hashCodeMethod))
            {
                return proxyHashCode(proxy);
            }
            else if (m.equals(equalsMethod))
            {
                return proxyEquals(proxy, args[0]);
            }
            else if (m.equals(toStringMethod))
            {
                return proxyToString(proxy);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InternalError(
                    "unexpected Object method dispatched: " + m);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (m.getName().equals(methodName))
            {
                return function.apply(args);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Integer proxyHashCode(Object proxy)
    {
        return new Integer(System.identityHashCode(proxy));
    }

    private Boolean proxyEquals(Object proxy, Object other)
    {
        return (proxy == other ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE);
    }

    private String proxyToString(Object proxy)
    {
        return proxy.getClass().getName() + '@' +
            Integer.toHexString(proxy.hashCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s worth noting that such a solution [already exists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/EventHandler.html) in Java itself since jdk1.4…

Comment: `EventHandler.create(listenerType, consumer, "accept", "", listenerMethodName)`

Comment: @Holger OK. This discussion can be cleaned up if you post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From Java 8 you can provide default implementation for interface methods. Create a new interface that extends WindowListener with all but one methods implemented:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface WindowOpenedListener extends WindowListener {
    @Override
    default void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {}

    @Override
    default void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {}

    @Override
    default void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {}

    @Override
    default void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {}

    @Override
    default void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {}

    @Override
    default void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {}
}
```

as you can see windowOpened is the only method that is left unimplemented by the interface, so you can:

```
window.addWindowListener((WindowOpenedListener) e -> {
    // windowsOpened implementation
});
```

One can generalize multiple methods (if it make sense), to do so implement all methods of WindowListener and add a new abstract one, like:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface WindowStatusListener extends WindowListener {
    void statusChanged(WindowEvent e);

    @Override
    default void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) { statusChanged(e); }

    @Override
    default void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {}

    @Override
    default void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) { statusChanged(e); }

    @Override
    default void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {}

    @Override
    default void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {}

    @Override
    default void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {}

    @Override
    default void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {}
}
```

and then

```
window.addWindowListener((WindowStatusListener) e -> {
    // statusChanged implementation
});
```