# Can FunctionalInterface extends a non-functionalinterface class?

Tags: java, interface, mouselistener, functional-interface

I'm studying at the moment and I've been given the simple (I thought so) task.
I have to make this piece of code to work (I can't modify it):

```
    JButton b = new JButton("MyszÄ… ciĹ›nij");
    b.addMouseListener ( (MousePressListener) e -> System.out.println("ok"));
```

I believe MousePressListener should be FunctionalInterface but then, it can't extend MouseListener. Is there any way to work around this issue, or am I approaching it from bad side?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25299653/java-idiom-for-lambdas-with-non-sam-interfaces and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833537/java-8-lambda-expressions-what-about-multiple-methods-in-nested-class

Comment: Why not make a random class `Foo` that is not a functional interface, make an interface `Bar` that extends `Foo` that has exactly one abstract method and add the `@FunctionalInterface` annotation to `Bar`? If `Bar` is not a functional interface in Java's eyes it will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

`addMouseListener` expects a `MouseListener`. `MouseListener` has multiple abstract methods. Therefore no lambda expression can be of type `MouseListener`.

I don't know what `MousePressListener`, but if it's an interface that extends `MouseListener`, it will still inherit multiple abstract methods from `MouseListener`, so it can't be a functional interface.

Comment: Actually, it can. Managed to do that by making "mouseClicked" abstract, and "mouseEntered", "mouseExited", "mousePressed" and "mouseReleased" default. Thank you for help, though :)