# java What is {{ }} and -> in the following enum

Tags: java, lambda, enums

I have a very basic doubt!
What does {{ }} and -> mean, and what does it mean for the following enum?

```
public enum BuyUsedFeatureFilters implements FeatureFilter {

    BuyUsedContext {{
        requestProperty = 
                req -> isBuyUsedContext(req);
    }};

    RequestProperty<Boolean> requestProperty;
    PropertyCondition defaultCondition = PropertyCondition.IGNORE;

    @Override
    public RequestProperty<Boolean> requestProperty() {
        return requestProperty;
    }


    private static boolean isBuyUsedContext(RequestContext requestContext){
        String buyUsedParam = requestContext.getParameters().get("buyUsedParam");

        if (StringUtils.equals(buyUsedParam, "buyUsed")) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: please refer to below posts. And let me know if any.
[What is Double Brace initialization in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java)
[lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36233477/implementing-an-interface-with-two-abstract-methods-by-a-lambda-expression/36233545#36233545)

Comment: @linc01n Double brace initialization creates an anonymous class - here the `{{` is applied to an enum constant declaration.

Comment: This looks like pretty terrible code. Whoever wrote it should have just used a constructor.

Comment: @assylias Double brace initialization creates an anonymous class. And that's exactly what it does here. An anonymous class that extends the enum `BuyUsedFeatureFilters`.

Comment: @assylias https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.1 "The optional class body of an enum constant implicitly **defines an anonymous class declaration** (§15.9.5) that extends the immediately enclosing enum type. "

Comment: Thanks a lot! these answers are very helpful

Answer (score 2):

That syntax is allowed by [JLS #8.9.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2) (emphasis mine):

> In addition to enum constants, the body of an enum declaration may contain constructor and member declarations ***as well as instance and static initializers***.

In your case, it's an instance initializer, which assigns a value to the `requestProperty` field. In your example, it is assigned a lambda expression.

Comment: Thanks a lot! these answers are very helpful